# Game Crashes when object gets near player

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

THIS POST IS NOW IRRELEVANT PLEASE CHECK MY NEWER ONE

I am making a horror game with next bots on VR (Quest/Quest2)

the player has 1 "Mixed" light on it and the bots use pathfinding AI with navmeshes and stuff but it seems that when the next bot gets within I'll say like 10 feet of the player and the player can see it and all the game just decides it wants to freeze and stop working!

It seems to happen before the player "Dies" but I'm not fully sure.

```
public class Kill : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    public GameObject tes;
    public GameObject LocoToOff;
    public Vector3 SPOT;
    public GameObject SprintLoco;
    public GameObject Dead;
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    private bool Using;
    public GameObject Safe;
    public LocomotionControllery Loco;
    private bool ChillOutItsGoing;

    IEnumerator TurnOff()
    {
        ChillOutItsGoing = true;
        LocoToOff.SetActive(false);
        SprintLoco.SetActive(false);

        Dead.SetActive(true);


        Loco.Disabled = true;

        audioSource.Play();

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);


        //foreach (var pls in WallsNStuff)
        //{
        //    pls.SetActive(false);
        //}


        tes.transform.position = SPOT;


        //yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);


        Loco.Disabled = false;

        Dead.SetActive(false);

        //foreach (var pls in WallsNStuff)
        //{
        //    pls.SetActive(true);
        //}

        Safe.SetActive(true);

        ChillOutItsGoing = false;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "BOT")
        {
            if (ChillOutItsGoing == false)
            {
                Debug.Log(other.gameObject.name);
                Using = LocoToOff.active;
                StartCoroutine(TurnOff());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If game freezes like this, it's might an indication of endless loop. Beside that, I can't say more until you post some code, for eg. parts when player dies, some loops from enemies, and other stuff you think might be the culprit.

Comment: Here is the kill script I have been commenting stuff out but Im not sure if its the issue Ill add it to the post

Comment: Not the kill script I removed It from the player than built the apk still it bugs out

Comment: Do you have any scripts with a `while` loop?  That is normally the culprit.

Comment: I believe so but the crash only happens when the player gets near the bot almost like as if it crashes when the bot is about to enter the players spotlight. Also about the while loop its in an IEnumerator yield waitforsecionds thing and it's for a totally different thing that is only related to the ai by a stretch

Comment: I know coroutines are popular in Unity and their use of `IEnumerator` and `yield` creating a hot debate in the C# world, but if the past is anything to go by, they should perhaps be _outlawed_. Numerous recent posts whereby **unguarded** `StartCoroutine` are spammed in either the `Update` or `OnTriggerEnter` methods leading to excessive coroutine sessions.  When you consider `Update` could be called as much as **60 times a second** or more, such code can be **hazardous**.   `StartCoroutine` may look innocent but I can't help but wonder it is as dangerous as `Application.DoEvents()`.

Comment: I fully removed the death script from the player which uses ontriggerenter and isn't the issue it freezes almost as the bot is about to enter the spotlight but thus only happens in the apk not the editor and the game doesn't crash as I still here things working even after it's frozen

Answer (score 0):

I believe it ended up just being because the thing was set to "Cutout" instead of opaque and Cutout I think is in alpha only 2 things I changed that fixed it for sure was setting it to opaque and adding a lil bit of smoothness (just did that idk if it was part of the fix or not)